# Delete the minimum value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an example that can't understand.
The code below is selecting the name and the grades for all students from my database.
I want to create a script that will delete the smallest grade of every student. **BUT** if the smallest grade is 3 for example and the student has 2 grades of 3, I would like to delete just one of them (random or the first one, I don't care, I don't want to put a rule for that); What I did here works ok, but is deleting all grades of 3.

```
 DECLARE 
     nume studenti.nume%TYPE;
     nota note_studenti.nota%TYPE;
     CURSOR myc IS SELECT nume, nota 
                     FROM studenti INNER JOIN note_studenti 
                       ON studenti.mat = note_studenti.mat;
 BEGIN
     OPEN myc;
     LOOP
         FETCH myc INTO nume, nota;
         EXIT WHEN myc%NOTFOUND;

     END LOOP;
     DELETE  FROM note_studenti WHERE nota = 
               (SELECT MIN(note_studenti.nota) FROM note_studenti);
     CLOSE myc;
 END;
```

LE: I figured out how to delete the smallest grade. 
Now I need just to make it delete only one row, not all of them.

Comment: use *LIMIT* in the end.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I tried with "LIMIT 1", "LIMIT = 1" and "FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY" but every time I got that error that my SQL command is not properly ended. I added the limit right after the last parenthesis.

Comment: DELETE  FROM note_studenti WHERE nota = (SELECT MIN(note_studenti.nota) FROM note_studenti) limit 1

Comment: @kashan: there is no `LIMIT` clause in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches.  The first uses `rownum` and the second `rowid`:

```
 DELETE FROM note_studenti
 WHERE nota = (SELECT MIN(note_studenti.nota) FROM note_studenti) and
       rownum = 1;
```

To be honest, although I think the above will work, I am not positive about how `rownum` will interact with the other condition in the `where` in a `delete` statement.

```
 DELETE FROM note_studenti
 WHERE rowid = (select rowid
                from (select *
                      from note_studenti
                      order by note desc
                     ) ns
                where rownum = 1
               );
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Not at all.  That has been fixed to be `rownum = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM note_studenti
WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM note_studenti
                WHERE nota = (SELECT MIN(note_studenti.nota) FROM note_studenti));

Answer (score 0):

*--You can Just do that by order by with limit --*
**DELETE FROM note_studenti ORDER BY nota limit 1 ;**